# Htaccess code to redirect from current page to previous page?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from current page to previous page..  I want this previous page button in most of the pages..

Is there any common htaccess code for all pages?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use javascript
history.go(-1)

Comment: you want to add an previous page button on most of the page that is the correct solution. It's a client-side action and do not need to spend extra unnecessary resource if perform by php, and htaccess also not meet you requirement